# Exchange EWS change permissions of another users calendar

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

imagine person A shares his calendar. How would Person B be able to modify the permissions of person A's calendar? I've tried giving OWNER-rights but this doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible without having impersonation rights?

tnx!

Comment: Might help if you provided the exchange version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?:
[Configuring Exchange Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)

Comment: See my question: "Is this possible without having impersonation rights?". It's a policy here that we don't impersonate. It's one account that would have access to 4000 mailboxes... not an option...